# Why does R's replicate turn a Date into a number?

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to build a tibble in R using some functions from the Python Faker library. All works fine except for dates, which are being turned into integers by `replicate()`.

Reproducible example below, with an example of it working fine without replicate at the bottom.

I assumed this was because `replicate()` is a wrapper for `sapply()` with `simplify = "array"`, however, using a copy of replicate didn't change the result (e.g. `replicate2 <- function(n, expr) sapply(intenger(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)))`).

```r
library(tidyverse); library(reticulate)

# Python Faker library
faker <- import("faker")
fake <- faker$Faker()

make_df <- function(N){ 
  txns <- tibble(
    date_time = replicate(5, fake$date_time_between(start_date = "-1y", 
                                                    end_date = "now") %>% 
                            str_extract("[0-9-]*") %>% lubridate::parse_date_time("Ymd"))
  )

  return(txns)
}

make_df(5)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>    date_time
#>        <dbl>
#> 1 1545177600
#> 2 1546473600
#> 3 1537833600
#> 4 1547596800
#> 5 1531008000


fake$date_time_between(start_date = "-1y", end_date = "now") %>% 
  str_extract("[0-9-]*") %>% lubridate::parse_date_time("Ymd")
#> [1] "2018-07-25 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Try using `simplify=FALSE`

Comment: Perfect, works. I thought the default in sapply was FALSE! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was just `simplify = FALSE`, as Mr. Flick commented.

Answer (score 1):

R Date-classed vectors are integers with a class of "Date" and a variety of generic functions that honor that class to produce behavior that users expect from such an object.  R arrays cannot hold objects with attributes, so coercion to an array will unclass objects are reveal their underlying storage class.

```
storage.mode( as.Date("1970-01-01"))
[1] "double"
```

Look at the output of

```
 print.Date
 '+.Date'
 diff.Date
```

And finally take any data object and do:

```
 dput(object)
```

And do look at:

```
  sapply
```

And those objects of yours were not Dates anyway, but rather POSIXct objects. They were floating point vectors with class "POSIXct".